# Book suggestions

Tags: machine-learning, python, books

Considering, I do have some knowledge about machine learning, python, data science through the courses I have done from sites like Udemy, Udacity, Edx.
However, I would like to read some books related to the subject matter. Could you please refer me to some helpful books related to machine learning, python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Python, [Python: The Complete Reference](https://www.amazon.in/Python-Complete-Reference-Martin-Brown/dp/9387572943/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=python%20book&qid=1599758714&sr=8-3) and [Head First Python](https://www.amazon.in/Head-First-Python-Brain-Friendly-Guide/dp/9352134826/ref=sr_1_1?crid=1E0OSYEZSHQY3&dchild=1&keywords=head%20first%20python&qid=1599758926&sprefix=Head%20first%20%2Caps%2C353&sr=8-1).These two should be good enough.

For Machine learning, it really depends whether you want to get into all the math or not. If not, I think there are enough resources online. But if you do, I would recommend [Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning](https://www.amazon.in/Pattern-Recognition-Learning-Information-Statistics/dp/0387310738/ref=tmm_hrd_swatch_0?_encoding=UTF8&qid=1599759042&sr=8-1) by Christopher Bishop. It really dives deep into the math for ML.